# Parse exception: com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: invalid session token

Tags: android, parse-platform

On my internship I must work with Parse.
I'm made now an android app in wich I am using this Parse Cloud.
I create a sign up button and if the user push this button, a new account should be create.
But after the pushing this button,I have this exception:

`com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: invalid session token`

I don't know my mistake.Android Studio don't show any errors and I am using this [instruction](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-login-and-signup-tutorial/).
My app was work fine yesterday morning and my first app that I am created for 1 week ago have now the same problem.
I have internet connection and restarted my tablet device.

My source code:

```
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();


user.setUsername(username); // String username = "Ivan"
user.setPassword(password); // String password = "Divan"



user.enableRevocableSessionInBackground();

user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {

    public void done(ParseException e) {

        if (e == null) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "Successfully Signed up, please log in.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "Sign up Error :" +e.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


});
```

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using the latest version [this tutorial](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/session-migration-tutorial) explain how to make a migration. Also check the versions for all the sdk you are using.